# Output lines from a CSV file based on duplicates in one of the columns (python)?

Tags: python, csv, duplicates, output

I have been trying to write a script that would output lines from a CSV based on duplicate values in the first column.

The data looks like this:

```
FULLNAME, ADDRESS_1, ADDRESS_2, CITY, STATE, ZIPCODE
JANE DOE, MAIN STREET 1, APT 1, METROPOLIS, NEW YORK, 10000
```

The script I am using looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('FILE.csv', dtype=str)
names = df["FULLNAME"]
df[names.isin(names[names.duplicated()])].sort_values("FULLNAME")

print(df)
```

The problem I am having is that instead of the lines that have a duplicate value for "FULLNAME", the whole file gets printed.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Your line works but you're just getting the values, not setting df. So when you do print(df), you're just printing the original list.

This will do what you want

```
# assign duplicate entries to variable dupes
dupes = df[names.isin(names[names.duplicated()])].sort_values("FULLNAME")
print(dupes)
```